# JavaScript object literal. Why can't I refer to a method via "this"?

Tags: javascript

Why can't I refer to a method of a JavaScript object by using "this"?
Like for example in `open();` method - why can't I call  `this.init();` ?

```
    var myModule = {

        //Initialize dek. Append html structure to the body
        init: function() {
            if (!$('.mwdek').length) {
                var dek = $(tpl);
                dek.find('.d-nav-close').on('click', function(e) {e.stopPropagation();e.preventDefault();
                    this.destroy();
                });
                dek.appendTo('body');
            }
            //var dek = $('.mwdek');

        },

        //Opens deck, makes it visible
        open: function() {
            if (!$('.mwdek').length) {
                this.init();
            }
            $('.mwdek').addClass('active');
        },

        //Removes deck html from the page
        destroy: function(messages) {
            $('.mwdek').remove();
        },

        //Pass in header text content
        setHeaderText: function() {

        }


    };
```

Comment: Your example should work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/xq17mmzy/ - what won't work is `this.destroy()` because that is inside a callback with a different `this` context

Comment: If you call `open` as `myModle.open()`, then `this.init()` will work just fine.

Comment: You can call `this.init`. I have a feeling your condition isn't true. Remove the condition and see if it gets called. Otherwise I think you are calling it with a different context. Please share how you are trying to invoke `open`.

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with `this.init()`  in `myModule.open()`. But [the `this.destroy()` call in that event handler will fail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572).

Comment: why down vote this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic looks good apart from 1 issue in your init function involving the `this` variable. In a statement like `object.method()`, within the `method` function, `this` refers to `object`. Keep this in mind.

Now, Here's the problematic portion of your code:

```
init: function() {
    if (!$('.mwdek').length) {
        var dek = $(tpl);
        dek.find('.d-nav-close').on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            this.destroy();     //THIS LINE has the issue!
        });
        dek.appendTo('body');
    }
}
```

The `this` variable on the line I commented is inside of an anonymous function you've written (`function(e) {...}`). This function is provided to JQuery to run when the appropriate click occurs. So JQuery is deciding how to call that function, which means that only JQuery really understands what `this` will refer to when the function is called. In your code, you rely on `this` pointing to the instance of `dek`, but that isn't the case. In order to solve this problem you can do the following (choosing to name the variable `that` is common convention):

```
init: function() {
    var that = this; //Maintain a reference to "this" even inside anonymous functions
    if (!$('.mwdek').length) {
        var dek = $(tpl);
        dek.find('.d-nav-close').on('click', function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            that.destroy();     //Originally "this.destroy();"
        });
        dek.appendTo('body');
    }
}
```